# relate complex user permissions to one table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have following table structure:

```
Entity
---------------------
id | name

Users
---------------------
id | name | password 

UserGroups
---------------------
id | parent_id | name

Users_UserGroups
---------------------
user_id | user_group_id

Roles
---------------------
id | parent_id | name

Users_Roles
--------------------
user_id | role_id
```

And main objective is create `Entity` row level access restrictions with following conditions:

1) User creates `Entity` - he can see it (he is owner)
2) User group members can see it too (but if defined else - not see - it will be user private). So record can be user or group private, or public - all can see record. For example user is in sales team A and there are records what can see all group members, but there can be one or more records what can see only user - maybe potential client.
3) For example user A is in role `salesman` and this role is child of parent role `sales managers`. Then user who is `sales manager` role can see user A entities. Hierarchy structure of roles. Boss can see what is doing his direct employees :)
4) There will be `profile` table too, where profile can be added to role and if needed, to user too.

Main question is how to relate users/groups/roles/profiles to entity? And how to define permissions? My idea was to create column 'user_id' into `Entity`. When query `Entity` record, find user, after see in which role, group, profile is user and so on. But I think that it is too complex, maybe there can be much easier way, without many additional tables. I would be grateful for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard pattern is to define Principal as anything you can assign permissions to. Then user, user group and role are all examples of principal. One way to implement is to have a principal table with principal_id as it's primary key, and then relate the user table to it via user_id, role table via role_id and group table via user_group_id.

Then you'd have an entity_owner_principal_id column on entity, and an entity_permissions table with entity_id, principal_id. You might add columns such as "read", "delete", "update" to this table, or have something more flexible.

You might also want to consider whether there is any real difference between group and role, they're both ways of grouping users, and you appear to have hierarchy in both too.

Comment: It would be something like [this](http://storenow.net/my/?f=5629)?1) What to do with `entity_owner_principal_id` - I think it is entity_permission_id or not? 2) How to properly name `Principal` table?  3) Will it be fast on analytic and complex queries (it is small part of big project)? Thank you!

Comment: something like that, although it would be good if your tool could show 1-1 relationships. I'm not sure about the modules bit, but I don't think the question was about that.

Comment: I updated previous comment - got some questions. Where to put 1 to 1 relation ships?

Comment: I would have the relationship between principal and user to be 1-1, id to id. I'd make principal the master end. Simiilarly I'd have principal to user_groups 1-1 with principal the master on id <-> id and the same for role. principal would have a sequential list of ids, the others would inherit their value from the principal record.

Comment: I updated diagram [here](http://storenow.net/my/?f=5630). What to do with `Entities` entity_owner_principal_id? I am not sure what is column for (it is meant for creator user_id?). Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see user_id, user_group_id or role_id in principal.  Entity_owner_principal_id should be a foreign key to principal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19765/discussion-between-orbitum-and-laurence)